# "Few" or "much" —was the test wrong?

Tags: exam-questions, quantifiers

I have a test with the following question. I was pretty sure that the correct answer is "few" but the test says that the answer is "much".

Is it right?

[image: Wrong answer?]

> 7. There are many clocks in the office but _____ of them work properly.
>
>    - little
>    - few
>    - much
>    - a little

Comment: The test is wrong. It's an online test, am I right? They bungle things up.  Write them an email pointing out the (computer) error, the answer is of course, as you rightly surmised,  *few*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a computer/programme error.

Comment: This kind of question doesn't belong here. But I am pretty sure you chose the correct answer.

Comment: Just because this came from a computer doesn't make it off-topic. If the OP had lied and said a school-teacher had said it, would that make it on-topic?

Comment: Here's the best piece of advice you will hear all life: if you want to learn English, never, ever take any tests. No native speaker ever took a test to learn English. In fact they all acquired fantastic command of the language before they even learned the word *test* existed. I suggest you do likewise.

Comment: Anyway, you know you're making progress when you can detect that the test is wrong!

Comment: @chasly: it's off-topic because it's about a test, rather than about English.

Comment: @RegDwigнt - Unfortunately it is a fact of life that entry to some institutions (and indeed some countries) requires the passing of such tests to 'prove' language proficiency. They also form an integral part of most formal language courses. Your sentiment is admirable but not really practical.

Comment: @TimLymington - This question falls within the remit, Here are a couple of quotes from the site guidelines, "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced."  and "[ask about] Word choice and usage". Could you show me anywhere that it says discussion of tests is prohibited? I'd be interested, thanks.

Comment: @TimLymington this question is perfectly acceptable.  There have been many questions asked that start with "I took a test but I think the answer is wrong because..."  It's not about the test...why is it few and not much?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I agree with you.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: [This question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/2819/8019) and [this one](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/2409/8019) say that if you ask about the test itself, rather the point of English raised, (as this question specifically does) it is off-topic. [This discussion](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/2409/8019) goes into why.  It also seems fairly obvious that a straightforward point, raised only because OP is not very familiar with the language, should be on ELL if anywhere.

Comment: @TimLymington,  You say, "it's off-topic because it's about a test". I read those links and they don't back up your argument at all. If you want to say it's off-topic because it belongs in ELL then fine. I see that people are saying it is off-topic because it is a software error. That is utter nonsense and shows no understanding of computers. I'm sure the software is working perfectly. The error came from a human putting in the wrong data when setting up the test. This is a classic case of confusing the medium with the message.

Answer (score 8):

The sentence is in two clauses, joined with *but*. That means that the second clause must qualify the first and negate its assertion.

The quantifier in the first clause is *many,* so the second clause must use a word or phrase which does not mean (or is the opposite of) *many.*

*Many* expresses a large number of **countable** objects, so the second clause needs a word which expresses a small number of countable objects.

That word is ***few.***

*Little* and *a little* are used for amounts of mass nouns: *a little mashed potato,* and oppose *much* or *a lot*. Neither is appropriate here because *clocks* is countable.

You were right, and the test answer is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The test is wrong.

COUNTABLE

Clocks are countable nouns (things that can be individually counted).  Countable nouns can be quantified with *few* or *many.*

Either of these sentences would be grammatically complete:

> There are many clocks in the office but **few** of them work properly.
>
> There are many clocks in the office but **many** of them work properly.

The second sentence sounds a little awkward, due to the repetition of *many,* but it is grammatically fine.  Maybe you asked your clock repairman if it would take a long time to repair all the clocks in the building.  He responds *"Not long - There are many clocks, but many of them are working fine [and don't need repair.]"*

UNCOUNTABLE

Suppose instead you were discussing sand on the floor.  Sand is not generally thought of as countable, and you would use *little* or *much*.

> There is a lot of sand in my goldpan but **little** of it is likely to contain any gold.
>
> The winds weren't too strong.  There is a lot of sand on the office but **much** of it was tracked in by the dog after the storm was over.

Comment: +1 This more complete than my very similar answer so I have deleted mine.